# $100 monero lost due to monero gui transaction history

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Today I was sending Monero to another wallet that I regularly send funds to. Instead of directly copying the address I was sending to, I decided to copy the address from my transaction history of the Monero wallet I was sending from. I read a few letters from the area I use to identify the sending wallet and they matched perfectly.

After sending I noticed I didn't receive my funds. After a while of panicking I decided to check the address that I sent to and the address that I was meant to send to and noticed they were slightly different. I guess what I'm trying to ask is will this money eventually go to the designated wallet that it was supposed to be sent to, or come back to mine, or have I been phished?

If anyone knows anything or has had a similar problem / experience let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> I decided to check the address that I sent to and the address that I was meant to send to and noticed they were slightly different...

If you sent to an address that is not the *exact* same address as intended, you have very likely lost your funds.